# Android Smack bottleneck at Chat.sendMessage

Tags: android, multithreading, xmpp, smack

I'm facing some performance issues when sending messages through android `smack` library. If I send several messages in a row without waiting, my ui gets temporary stuck till all the messages are sent, even though I'm sending them on a background thread.

The relevant code where I send a message looks like this.-

**XMPPHelper.java**

```
public void sendMessage(final MessageDto message, final UserDto user) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Chat chat = getChat(userJid);
            try {
                chat.sendMessage(message);

            } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }).start();
}
```

The bottleneck is on the line

```
chat.sendMessage(message.getMessage());
```

Anyone facing similar performance issues or could point me in the right direction to boost message sending performance?

**EDIT**

Here's how I call the method that runs the thread.-

**MyActivity.java**

```
...
textMessage.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        sendMessage(textMessage);
        return true;
    }
});

private void sendMessage(EditText textMessage) {
    // ... 
    // Some code to add the message to a ListView
    // ...

    XMPPHelper.getInstance().sendMessage(message, user);
    textMessage.getText().clear();
}
```

*As a side note, network connection seems pretty fast, a single message is sent in less than a second. I'm guessing Smack internally keeps some kind of message queue, does it make sense?*

Comment: Well, sendMessage() does a network call, and depending on the network conditions it may take time. However, your UI should normally remain responsive if you're doing the network call on a background thread. Could you please post the code that starts the background thread?

Comment: Thanks @Egor, that's what I thought, not a clue what's going wrong. Just updated the question, may it have something to do with the `onEditorActionListener`?

Comment: Smack's sendMessage() does not perform a "network call". It will only block it the used queue is full, which is unlikely if your network is fast. The reason for your bottleneck is likely somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, it seems the problem is on `EditorActionListener`. Just tried a simple button that sends a predefined message, and works with no ui issues.